# Repeatable write to SQL Sink using Azure Data Factory is failing

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

Scenario: I'm copying data from Azure Table Storage to an Azure SQL DB using an upsert stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[upsertCustomer] @customerTransaction dbo.CustomerTransaction READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE customerTransactionstable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target_sqldb
    USING @customerTransaction AS source_tblstg
    ON (target_sqldb.customerReferenceId = source_tblstg.customerReferenceId AND
        target_sqldb.Timestamp = source_tblstg.Timestamp)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            AccountId = source_tblstg.AccountId,
            TransactionId = source_tblstg.TransactionId,
            CustomerName = source_tblstg.CustomerName
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
            AccountId,
            TransactionId,
            CustomerName,
            CustomerReferenceId,
            Timestamp
            )
        VALUES (
            source_tblstg.AccountId,
            source_tblstg.TransactionId,
            source_tblstg.CustomerName,
            source_tblstg.CustomerReferenceId,
            source_tblstg.Timestamp
            );
END

GO
```

where **customerReferenceId** & **Timestamp** constitute the composite key for the **CustomerTransactionstable**

However, when I update the rows in my source(Azure table) and rerun the Azure data factory, I see this error:

> "ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A
>   database operation failed with the following error: 'Violation of
>   PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CustomerTransactionstable'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.CustomerTransactionstable'. The duplicate key value is
>   (Dec 31 1990 12:49AM, ABCDEFGHIGK).\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated.',Source=.Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider,SqlErrorNumber=2627,Class=14,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=14,Number=2627,State=1,Message=Violation
>   of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CustomerTransactionstable'"

Now, I have verified that there's only one row in both the source and sink with a matching primary key, the only difference is that some columns in my source row have been updated.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-repeatable-copy#repeatable-write-to-sqlsink) in the Azure documentation speaks about the repeatable copying, however I don't want to delete rows for a time range from my destination before inserting any data nor do I have the ability to add a new sliceIdentifierColumn to my existing table or any schema change.

**Questions**:

1. Is there something wrong with my upsert logic? If yes, is there a better way to do upsert to Azure SQL DBs?
2. If I choose to use a SQL cleanup script, is there a way to delete only those rows from my Sink that match my primary key?

**Edit**:

> This has now been resolved.

**Solution**:

> The primary key violation will only occur if it's trying to insert a
>   record which already has a matching primary key. In my case there
>   although there was just one record in the sink, the condition on which
>   the merge was being done wasn't getting satisfied due to mismatch
>   between **datetime** and **datetimeoffset** fields.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it using ADF Data Flows with Mapping Data Flows instead of coding it through a stored procedure? It may be much easier for you for upserts with SQL.

With an Alter Row transformation, you can perform Upsert, Update, Delete, Insert via UI settings and picking a PK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-alter-row

You would still just need a Copy Activity prior to your Data Flow activity to copy the data from Table Storage. Put it in a Blob folder and then Data Flow can read the Source from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark. This doesn't solve my problem but good to know there's an alternative.